# Pentaho - Kettle: can I execute a SQL script on the outputs of a previous step?

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I have a Pentaho - Kettle transformation which loads data from two separate csv files, then applies a 'unique rows(hashset)' transformation.

Can I execute a SQL script based on the output of the 'unique rows' step? I'd like to run something like

```
select field1, sum(field2) as MyCalc
from InputTable
group by field1
having sum(field2) > 100
```

where InputTable is not a table in a SQL database, but the output of the unique rows step.

Is this even possible?

Shall I output the result of 'unique rows' to a temporary table in a database? The point is I would like this to be run by people who will not have write access to the database; I might give them access to write temporary tables but that's about it.

Thank you!

PS Yes, I know that for something as banal as above I can use a 'group by' step, but what I have in mind is way more complex than that and, as far as I know, cannot really be achieved with a predefined step.

Answer (score 0):

Carrying on @Rishu's answer in order to revise it:
This is **exactly** the type of application for which PDI is out there.

Consider the following a scope of one job, and two sub-transformations.

- *Main Job*

  - *Transformation I:* get substitute columns

    1. Do whatever logic to generate the column names
    2. Use the *Copy rows to result* step to output the column names in a single row
    3. This transformation will pass on parameters to the one that follows it:
  - *Transformation II:* Query the database

    1. Get the parameters from the previous transformation (change the transformation's properties from the parent job's scope!)
    2. Query the database, exactly as suggested below, with variable substitutes ensured by checking the *Replace variables in script?* check-box in the table input step.

```sql
/* the following may look like a very invalid SQL query, 
   but that's how PDI would replace the variables with their values */
select 
  ${SQLSubstitutes.Field1}, 
  ${SQLSubstitutes.Field2} as MyCalc
from 
  InputTable
group by 
  ${SQLSubstitutes.Field1}
having 
  sum(${SQLSubstitutes.Field2}) > 100
```

I hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score -1):

If i am not wrong, i think you cannot substitute the table names with the values from your csv files. i have tried replicating your requirement with the SQL query (db: PostgreSQL):

```
select field1, max(field2) from (select 1,2 as field1, 2,3 as field2) a 
group by a.field1
```

assuming the values of field1 and field2 are coming from the csv files. Its not fetting the desired result.

One solution which i think you can try is to insert these csv data into a table and then run your query.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This answer is not entirely accurate. One of PDI's most common applications is the ability to create dynamic queries to databases. Stating that one cannot substitute table names with values from your CSV files is a very broad statement. Dynamic statements in PDI transformations are formed with variables and not fields from the transformation's row sets, and if you look at it that way, you've got your solution(s) in front of you.